# On proving that $(x+y)^z+(x+z)^y+(y+z)^x > 2 $ with $x,y,z > 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, exponential-function, fractions

I would like to show that $(x+y)^z+(x+z)^y+(y+z)^x > 2 $ with $x,y,z > 0$.

My attempts, I feel, have been going nowhere. How could this be proven?

Comment: Please describe your attempts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The hint:

If one of variables is greater or equal to $1$ then it's obvious.

But for $\{x,y,z\}\subset(0,1)$ by Bernoulli we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}(x+y)^z>\sum_{cyc}\frac{x+y}{x+y+z}=2.$$

I used the following Bernoulli:
$$(x+y)^z=\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{1}{x+y}-1\right)^z}\geq\frac{1}{1+z\left(\frac{1}{x+y}-1\right)}=\frac{x+y}{x+y+z-z(x+y)}>\frac{x+y}{x+y+z}.$$

Comment: Can you elaborate the use of Bernoulli $$(1+x)^r \le 1 + rx \quad \forall\, r \in (0,1), x \ge -1$$ in your answer?

Comment: @GNU Supporter I added it for you. See now.